# how to output float to tiff using CImg?

Tags: c++, image-processing, tiff, cimg

I'm trying to have float values in a .tiff file. The values in display are fine, but once on disk, it is unsigned short.

```
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include "CImg.h"
#define cimg_use_tif

using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    CImg<float> imgFloat(640, 400);

    for(int i=0; i<640; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<400; j++)
            imgFloat(i,j) = float(i*640+j)/10000;

    imgFloat.save_tiff("V_float.tiff"); // cant get anything but unsigned short in the actual output

    imgFloat.display();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the TIFF image file format supports `float`s? And if it does, how you need to store them? As in; have you done basic research on the file format you are trying to use? (Details about that should be *in* the question).

Comment: `return(0);` - `return` is a keyword, not a function. `return 0;` .

Comment: From looking at the source code, it looks like CImg supports writing floating-point TIFF files.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Indeed it does, as long as you tell it to do so by `#define cimg_use_tif` **before** `#include "CImg.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
#define cimg_use_tif
```

**before** (i.e. above)

```
#include "CImg.h"
```

Or actually, preferably define it on the compilation command-line:

```
g++ -D cimg_use_tif ...
```